# Installing proprietary nvidia drivers while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got a GeForce 6150 that unfortunately suffers bad corruption problems under the open source nVidia drivers in Linux. So bad sometimes I cannot see anything on screen.

Is there any way to install the proprietary nVidia drivers WHILE installing Ubuntu so that I can simply fully bypass the open source drivers?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, when you install the newest version from the NVidia site, it also uninstalls the version from the repository, so that it won't get overwritten again when you update. That would mean you'd always have to update the driver from the site manually though. I haven't found a way to make the proprietary driver update automatically.